# Combined Regex Validators with Or Operator in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

How do I add more Regex Validators as an Or Combined Option? For example, following Regex is created allowing customer to input Phone Number with hyphens

```
export const PhoneNumberValidator = Validators.pattern(/^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/);
```

555-555-5555 (with hyphens)

Now business department enables option for customer to enter Phone Number without any Hyphens, so they can use hyphens or no hyphens. This needs to be added in. How can this be done with stored validators and reactive form builders?

```
(/^[0][1-9]\d{9}$|^[1-9]\d{9}$/)
```

-

```
this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'phoneNumber': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50), PhoneNumberValidator]],
```

Comment: do you want to allow user with regex one as well as regex two?

Comment: don't care, as long as they can input Both phone With hyphens or No Hyphens, answer is good, prefer 1 export const validator

Comment: I think you need `Validators.compose( ValidatorFn[] )` description from angular doc  -> `Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the union of the individual error maps for the provided control.`  https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom validator with both the regex. Now both type of phone numbers will be allowed.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-example-kgvgpw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
export const PhoneNumberValidator = (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {

  if (!/^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/.test(control.value)
      &&
      !/^[0][1-9]\d{9}$|^[1-9]\d{9}$/.test(control.value)) {
    return { 'NOT_VALID': 'Not valid phone number' };
  }
}
```

**OR using `|` in between both regex**

```js
export const PhoneNumberValidator = Validators.pattern(/^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$|^[0][1-9]\d{9}$|^[1-9]\d{9}$/);
```

Comment: thanks, this works, can we remove the comment , not valid phone number,  and what is test? is that necessary also? just trying to slim it down to bear essentials,

Comment: see the original validator in question, want to keeps in similar format,

Comment: `test` is javascript function to validate regex. So that mandatory. Why I am saying custom validator because Validators always work in logical AND, so to achieve logical or you need to write custom validator.

Comment: ok cool, can also I just return null blank instead of not valid? don't need any return message, unless its required in javascript

Comment: Validator requires some value while sending the result, so no you need return value. I have updated the answer with another way. Take a look. But I will prefer the custom validator as I ll have more control over it